# How can we stop the HTML Form Submit button, when any of the value will not be accurate

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery-validate

I would like to stop the submit button function, when we got any error in HTML form elements (like captcha). We have several functions in our script, let me explain in details.

1. Check the data validation only captcha security code configured with PHP (through - jquery-1.3.2.js &&  - validate.js)
2. Send data through AJAX call (through - ajaxSubmit.js)

now i would like to stop the script, when any of the user filled the wrong value in Captcha text. we just simply disable the submit button and get message ("Form Not Filled Properly...")

UPDATED   VALIDATION - please check only with Captcha codes

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$.validator.addMethod('myEqual', function (value, element) {
 if ($('#password-password').val() == $('#password-password-confirm').val()) {
      return true;
 }    else return false;
}, 'Your password does not match.');




  $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#password-clear').show();
$('#password-password').hide();

$('#password-clear').focus(function() {
    $('#password-clear').hide();
    $('#password-password').show();
    $('#password-password').focus();
});
$('#password-password').blur(function() {
    if($('#password-password').val() == '') {
        $('#password-clear').show();
        $('#password-password').hide();
    }
});

    $('#password-clear-confirm').show();
$('#password-password-confirm').hide();

$('#password-clear-confirm').focus(function() {
    $('#password-clear-confirm').hide();
    $('#password-password-confirm').show();
    $('#password-password-confirm').focus();
});
$('#password-password-confirm').blur(function() {
    if($('#password-password-confirm').val() == '') {
        $('#password-clear-confirm').show();
        $('#password-password-confirm').hide();
    }
});


var validator = $("#signupform").validate({

    //ignore: ".ignore",

    rules: {

        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },

        captcha: {
            required: true,
            remote: "includes/process.php"
        },

        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        passwordconfirm: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            myEqual: true
        },

        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {


        captcha: "Correct captcha is required. Click the captcha to generate a new one",
        username: {
            required: "Enter a username",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),

        },
        password: {
            required: "Provide a password",
            rangelength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        },
        passwordconfirm: {
            required: "Provide a password",
            rangelength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        },
    email: {
            required: "Please enter a valid email address",
            minlength: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }


    },
    // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if ( element.is(":radio") )
            error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() );
        else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
            error.appendTo ( element.next() );
        else

            error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
    },

            submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    },

    // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {
        // set &nbsp; as text for IE
        label.html("").addClass("checked");
                      //  form.submit();
    }
});

 });
```

Please suggest me proper code for our requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$("#formid").submit(function (){
  if(!your condition){
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: how can we check the data with remote file includes/process.php ... it's giving "False" value when it does't match with user input and "True" for the vice versa condition.  Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Use the onSumbit attribute o fteh form. Assign it the function that you use to check for correct form completion. If the form is correctly filled out then return true; otherwise return false. False will stop the form from being submitted. You could display the required message just before returning false.

Comment: could you please provide me some codes. actually i m bigginer in Javascript, AJAX.

Comment: form.onsubmit = function(){ if (ok) { return true; } else { return false; } }

Comment: jQuery is not my thing, sorry.